# Getting a Segmentation fault (core dumped) error when I execute my code

Tags: c, while-loop, segmentation-fault

I'm doing a project for my C programming class and everything was working up until I added a while loop on line 22 in order to run the code over and over to print a triangle based on a users input. The first iteration of the code still works, however when it takes the input to determine how to update the code and run it again, I get a seg fault and I can't understand why. My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int size = 0;
    char symbol = ' ';
    int i = 0;
    int space = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int oldSize = 0;
    char oldSymbol = ' ';
    char menuChoice = ' ';
    
    printf("Please enter the size of the triangle (2-40): ");
    scanf("%d", &size);
    printf("Please enter the character you would like to use: ");
    scanf(" %c", &symbol);
    
    oldSize = size;
    oldSymbol = symbol;
    
    while (menuChoice != 'Q' || menuChoice != 'q') {
        if (size < 2 || size > 40) {
            size = 5;
            symbol = '*';
            printf("Error: Size outside bounds. Printing default triangle: \n");
        }
        for(i = 1; i <= size + 1; ++i, n = 0) {
            for(space = 1; space <= size + 1 - i; ++space) {
                printf(" ");
            }
            while (n != i - 1) {
                printf("%c ", symbol);
                ++n;
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    
        printf("G: Grow the current triangle\n");
        printf("S: Shrink the current triangle\n");
        printf("N: Draw a new triangle\n");
        printf("Q: Quit\n");
    
        scanf(" %c", menuChoice);
    
        if (menuChoice == 'G' || menuChoice == 'g') {
            size = size + 1;
            
        } else if (menuChoice == 'S' || menuChoice == 's') {
            size = size - 1;

        } else if (menuChoice == 'N' || menuChoice == 'n') {
            size = oldSize;
            symbol = oldSymbol;
            
        } else {
            printf("Error: please enter a valid argument.");
        }
    }
    printf("Goodbye");
}
```

Comment: `scanf(" %c", menuChoice);` ==> `scanf(" %c", &menuChoice);`

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings, they'll catch that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
scanf(" %c", menuChoice);
```

is clearly incorrect, and you know how to call this from other places in the code you uploaded. You want

```
scanf(" %c", &menuChoice);
```

I didn't spot any other similar mistakes and there are no other pointer-constructs in this code, so that should be the end of it.

Comment: Welp. I've got nothing to defend myself there.